# Best method to pull external list data from one SP farm to another?

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, active-directory

I was thinking of using owssvr, supplying the list GUID, then just parsing that data. Is there any better methods? I need to provide credentials to get that data, I need to have an account that can at least authenticate against AD. (Internal security requirements).

My base call would look like this:

```
//XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    //xDoc.Load("<localsite>/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={8C3DE28C-00EF-40CE-8FD1-2D76D7F85426}&XMLDATA=TRUE");//hard coded for testing
/*This is where I'd parse the xDoc*/
```

Is there any better method to do this? I'm stuck with the credential issue at the moment. Both farms are SharePoint 2007, can they share better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xmlUrlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver { Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials };
var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader("http://yoururl") { XmlResolver = xmlUrlResolver };

var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlTextReader);
```

You may be able to reduce this code further but it gives you some direction for further investigation.
Notice I am using .NET 4 LINQ to XML clases.

For the Xml DOM version, the first 2 lines remain the same:

```
var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(xmlTextReader);
```

Comment: Weirdly, this was working, but now after I did a IISRESET on the box pulling data, I can't get it to pull data from the external SP site. Do you know what might have changed?

Comment: I've wrapped it in a SPSecurity.RunWithElevated() and that works. Is that good practice?

Thanks,